# .Net BackgroundService in Multi Server Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I've created a `BackgroundService` in a `WebAPI` based on the code examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice .  The article doesn't give any guidance for implementing this in a multi-server environment.  My use-case involves a `FileSystemWatcher` monitoring a shared network folder for changes.  It works great.

The issue is there will be multiple instances of this and I don't want all of the instances responding - just one.  Is this feasible, and if so, what steps do I need to implement?  I've read about using queues, but I can't see how that will help.  Also, `Hangfire` or similar is not an option.  Do I need to re-examine my logic?

Answer (score 3):

I can think of multiple ways to achieve this, with pros and cons.

### Individual service

If you need only one instance of this, implement it as a standalone service and deploy on one server only. True, you can't leverage background processes, but do you really need to?

### Configuration

Have a config value indicating where to register the service. This could be comma separated values and whatnot. This will require some deployment handling though, to change the config to on, on the server running the background service. It could even be a comma separated value to indicate server names.

### Persist value in db

If there is a single database somewhere, you can have the services communicating through it. Have a table storing which server executes the background service and once the first one locks it, then the others just sleep. Some keep alive logic needs to be implemented as well.

I would honestly go with solution one. Individually scalable, deployable and no workaround needed.

A background service, indicates that it should be running on all instances if it's part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go with microservice architecture.

- On microserver will use file watcher and prepare queue
- then you can have another microserver which works up that queue msg(this you can scale with multiple instance )
- you also make another service/microservice to keep eye on the health of file watcher and do failover task

Comment: Can you provide any links/documentation for this?  I'm assuming you really mean "microserver" and not "microservices" :)

Comment: Microservers may not be an option at this point.  Need to stick with APIs

Comment: I mean microservice

Comment: you can refer this framework  https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/

Comment: You said "On microserver will use file watcher and prepare queue".  The services are all load balanced, so there are multiple servers per microservice.  All of them will respond to file watcher actions and this is what I need to avoid.

Comment: you should have only one instance of file watcher microservice and that service will be watching by another service for the health check and failover scenario.